# install ilog res and invoke

Tags: ejb, weblogic9.x, ilog

It's the first time I work with Jrules Ilog7.0.1 and WebLogic 9.2. Here are the install steps:

1. Enabling Anonymous Admin Server Lookup for MBeans
2. Adding new groups and users
3. Deploying the jrules-res-xu-WL92.rar
4. Deploying the Rule Execution Server Management EAR:jrules-res-management-WL92.ear
5. Opening the Rule Execution Server Console
6. Running database scripts using the Installation Manager
7. Running the Rule Execution Server diagnostics, and all items are green

Then I deployed a `ruleApp` successfully, but invoking failed.
Here is the error message:

`javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve 'ejb.IlrStatelessRuleSessionEJB'. Resolved 'ejb'`

There is not much documentation on this issue. Has someone faced a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

resolved.
after the 4th step,we must also intall jrules-res-session-WL92.jar to supply ejb service.
remember must Install this deployments as an application, not library, or it will not work to supply ejb service.